# How do I make my report heading repeat on overflow pages

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reporting

I am using report.rdlc components in my application. I have one report where I have a tablix table embedded in a tablix list. The top of the list above the table contains all the group variables, eg customer name, customer address; the table contains the details, eg order details. I need to display the customer information again when there are too many order details to display on one page and I also need to display the order detail column headings again on the new page. So far I have played around with the Tablix properties and the Static row properties but no matter what I have tried I cannot get the headings to repeat. Can anyone help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you group the tablix for customer? If so you can add the customer information to your column headers and set those to repeat on each page in your tablix properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying here. I did group for customer but if you are suggesting I add customer details to every row in the table part, I don't want to do that. If that is not what you are suggesting, then I don't know how to do what you are suggesting. We relley need scrren shots here :-(